# EventList from calendar

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, calendar, recurring

I am developing a calendar application,where i have created a recurring event n native BB calendar which starts from 1st jan and ends on 3rd jan .So when i use the below api

```
private EventList getEventList() {
        EventList eventList = null;
        try {
            eventList = (EventList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
                    PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
            Enumeration events = eventList.items();
            while (events.hasMoreElements()) {

                Event event = (Event) events.nextElement();
                int eve = eventList.OCCURRING;
                System.out.println("eve" + eve);
                long start = event.getDate(Event.START, 0);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
                String date = sdf.formatLocal(start);
                System.out.println("List of dates:" + date);

                System.out.println("event is:" + event);
            }
        }
```

This gives me only the date 1st jan it is not retruning 2nd and 3rd jan dates.This issue is only with evetns which are recurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call event.getRepeat() to get the RepeatRule object associated with the event.  Note that it can be null if the event isn't recurring.

Then check out the [dates function](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/RepeatRule.html#dates%28long,%20long,%20long%29) which can give you a list of the dates it occurs on in some range.

Comment: ya you are right,we need to use dates function to get the repeat instance dates.